# How to get the second word from a String?

Tags: java, regex

Take these examples

```
Smith John
Smith-Crane John
Smith-Crane John-Henry
Smith-Crane John Henry
```

I would like to get the `John`
The first word after the space, but it might not be until the end, it can be until a non alpha character. How would this be in Java 1.5?

Comment: In your third example is the correct output "John" or "John-Henry"?

Comment: WTF is the "possible"-homework tag?

Comment: Your title and your question don't quite agree. In general the second word isn't necessarily the first word after the space. You're assuming that there is a word before the first space, which in general doesn't need to be true (e.g. `-###- Foo`). Do we need to consider this special case, and if so, which behaviour do you want? The one in your title, or the one in your question?

Comment: @Neil N: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged

Comment: It's not a homework, I am just missing the expertise in this area, sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: @Mark Byers, keep it simple, this will be run on names only. What you have posted sounds good.

Comment: If you have `A B` you should get B. If you have `A-X B` you should get B. If you have `A-X B-Y` why would you get B instead of B-Y?

Comment: Because I only need to call them by their first name.

Comment: If there's a hyphen in it, it's one word. If John-Henry somehow represents multiple names, then the representation is totally wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and the [**`Matcher`**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class:

```
String s = "Smith-Crane John-Henry";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s([A-Za-z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
John
```

Comment: +1, but I'd use `group(1)` else it will return the entire match, including leading space.

Comment: What if the person's name is for example Hélenè? Use `\p{L}` to match all Unicode letters instead of using `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [String.split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
line.split(" ");
```

Which for the first line would yield:

```
{ "Smith", "John" }
```

You could then iterate over the array to find it. You can also use regular expressions as the delimiter if necessary.

Is this good enough, or do you need something more robust?

Comment: Fails on 3rd example though. He want to get `John`, not `John-Henry`.

Comment: It would be good if it could recognize only John from John-Henry

Comment: not sure if the original author intended to grab a particular item in the input, but if you use split as Justin suggested, use equalsIgnoreCase to test if the item is the particular item you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a regular expression like the follwoing.

```
\s{1}[A-Z-a-z]+
```

Enjoy!

Comment: What will you capture? because this may not work when the space or hyphen is present in the name.

Comment: Hi Pran,

Yes on the contrary this expression reads as follows - find the first occurrence of a single space then one or more alpa characters following the space. So it will look for this signature weather a hyphen is following in the alpha string or not.  As you can see Mark Byers used my expression in his answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I really like the string tokenizer.  I know it's out of style these days with split being so easy and all, but...

(Psuedocode because of high probability of homework)

```
create new string tokenizer using (" -") as separators
iterate for each token--tell it to return separators as tokens
    if token is " "
        return next token;
```

done.

Comment: Perhaps put it in a blockquote instead of a code sample to avoid syntax highlighting

Comment: StringTokenizer is so 2006. :-) As per the Javadoc, `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split  method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.`

Comment: @glowcoder I can't figure out how to get split to do what tokenizer does naturally--return separators as tokens.

Comment: you don't with split. Split isn't intended to return the delimiters. You can use the Pattern/Matcher paradigm to return delimiters. I didn't completely vet the code, but `http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6453` seemed to have an example of doing so.

Comment: But then you are using REs.  I admit that it's possibly a better solution, but personally I'll stick with tokenizer, it does exactly what I need and does it the way I prefer (Personally I'm quite anti regular expressions, admittedly an unpopular stance, but until I'm somehow actually presented with a way they will make my life better rather than worse, I'll stick with it.)